# Neo4j how to create relationships of nodes in neo4j within a list?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to connect a first node of a list with other nodes of the list via relationship in Neo4j.

My approach is :

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n.title AS id, COLLECT(n) as nodes
where size(nodes)>1 ,COALESCE(COLLECT(n)) as firstNode  
UNWIND TAIL(nodes) as x
CREATE (firstNode)-[r:Child]->(x)
return r
```

Basically I have some nodes with same titles. I want them to club together and make one of the element of that same title group as superior by creating a child relationship with other nodes in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n.title AS id, collect(n) as nodes
WHERE size(nodes) > 1
WITH nodes[0] as firstNode, nodes[1..] as otherNodes
UNWIND otherNodes as other
CREATE (firstNode)-[r:Child]->(other)
```

In the second `WITH` I'm extracting the first node and a list from the second node to the end of the list. Then I unwind the `otherNodes` list and create the desired relationship between the `firstNode` and the unwinded nodes.

Comment: Thanks it did work ! Can you assist me if i  want to use combination of more than one attribute  along with title as an id for collect function .How can i do that ? @brunoperes

Comment: @nikhil024 You are welcome! Sure, I can try help you. But can you be more  specific? Maybe providing an example... Also, I suggest you to make a new question instead of using the comments for it. Its better because the whole community can help you and the efforts to solve your issue can benefit other users with the same problem. :)